# SSHFS: send remote setup commands before mounting

Tags: ssh, router, sshfs

I am trying to mount through sshfs (with osxfuse, former macfuse) a folder on a router.
Unfortunately the router doesn't replay directly with a standard command line but requires a couple of commands to invoke it, something like this:

```
local$ ssh user@router
Password:
OpenDG> system
OpenDG> shell
remote$
```

To have it working I would therefore need to send some commands at the very beginning of the ssh session, before changing remote folder and mounting it.
Unfortunately, looking at sshfs arguments, I fail to find anything related.

Do you have any idea how to handle this?
Help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

Set up password-less ssh for that router then make a script to send commands via ssh `local$ ssh router system` and then `local$ ssh router shell` and then put your sshfs command last.

[`.ssh/rc` is another option](https://superuser.com/questions/124101/run-a-remote-command-using-ssh-config-file).